# QAF - Webservices testing not fetching Xpath value from XML

Tags: xml, web-services, xpath, bdd, qaf

I'm trying to do Webservices Testing using QAF 3.0
Below is my BDD for the Test.

```
Scenario: [WS-2]_[222-xml]_Sample XML Webservices
    When I request api "get.mock.xml.menu"
    Then I check api response status code is "200"
    And I check api response status is "OK"
    And I check api response should have xpath '/breakfast_menu'
```

First three lines are executing without any issues. Internally I'm calling QAF WsStep.

> Note: Json path verification is working perfectly without any issues.

StepDef:

```
@QAFTestStep(description = "I check api response should have xpath {xpath}")
public static void iCheckApiResponseShouldHaveXpath(String xpath) {
    WsStep.responseShouldHaveXpath(xpath);
}
```

Comment: <breakfast_menu>
  <food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles
    </name>
    <price>$5.95
    </price>
    <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
    </description>
    <calories>650
    </calories>
  </food>
  <food>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles
    </name>
    <price>$7.95
    </price>
    <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream
    </description>
    <calories>900
    </calories>
  </food>
</breakfast_menu>

Comment: Try `//breakfast_menu`. You should check command log in qaf report and share request response details from command log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `breakfast_menu` is root node, so it will be consider as context (root) and will be accessible as `.`. You should be able to use following xpaths:

```
.
./food
//food
./food/name
./food[name='Belgian Waffles']
//food[name='Belgian Waffles']
//*[name='Belgian Waffles']
```